# process a file stored remotely on web

Tags: c#, .net

Can I just use File.Open to open such file? Is it the recommended way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the file using WebRequest or WebClient classes and then you can open it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).